# Moving to new DB server on Web 8 with TopologyManager and CMS

Tags: content-manager, database, topology-manager

On a Web 8 instance, the TopologyManager and CMS Databases are installed on the same DB server.

The DB server will change and we will move the Databases to the new server.

For the CMS, we can update the DB server name in the MMC console and also follow the steps here, [Correct steps when changing CM database](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/12642/correct-steps-when-changing-cm-database).  But, what about for the TopologyManager database?

Comment: are you able to resolve it now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Database connection string of Topology Manager is part of encrypted section in web.config of "SDL Web Topology Manager" project.

You have to decry-pt it, update and again encrypt on your server.

**Decrypt command**:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319>aspnet_regiis -pdf "database" "C
:\Program Files (x86)\SDL Web\TopologyManager\web"
```

**Encrypt**:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319>aspnet_regiis -pef "database" "C
:\Program Files (x86)\SDL Web\TopologyManager\web"
```